# Custom comparison using Comparator

Tags: java

I have a variable which can take on three possible values ( or status ) : `Available, Partial, Not Available`.

Now, I have a list of these statuses. My job is to to summarize the entire result onto one status. I mean that even if one of the status in the list is `Not Available`, then the overall status becomes `Not Available`.

If all the statuses in the list are `Available`, while one is `Partial`, then the overall status is `Partial`.

Currently, I am doing using a very naive approach where by I have a value corresponding to each possible status and then I am comparing them one by one.

```
public class StringsInCusomOrder {

public static String overallStatus(ArrayList<String> statusList) throws Exception
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("Available", 0);
    map.put("Partial", 1);
    map.put("Not Available", 2);

    String overallstatus = "Available";
    int value = 0;

    for( String s : statusList)
    {
        if(map.get(s) > value)
        {
            overallstatus = s;
            value = map.get(s);             
        }
    }
    return overallstatus;

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<String> statusList = new ArrayList<String>();
    statusList.add("Available");
    statusList.add("Partial");
    statusList.add("Not Available");
    statusList.add("Partial");

    System.out.println(overallStatus(statusList));
}
}
```

I wondered if there is a better approach of doing this ? Can I use comparator to do this custom comparison ?

Comment: Can't you just use the `contains` method?

Comment: Since your code is working, you may want to post at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you'd like to discuss a better way of doing it.

Comment: You might also consider using an `enum` instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `contains` operation then it is worth noting that this is `O(n)` for a `List` but only `O(1)` for a `Set` so a cleaner approach would be:

```
public String getStatus(final Collection<String> in) {
    final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(in);
    if (set.contains("Not Available")) {
        return "Not Available";
    }
    if (set.contains("Partial")) {
        return "Partial";
    }
    return "Available";
}
```

I prefer my `enum` based approach however as this is a fast road to a tyranny of `if`s.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an Enum for the status values instead of a String.
You can then simply use `Collections.min()` to get the lowest value of your EnumSet like so:

```
public Enum Status {
  NOT_AVAILABLE,
  PARTIAL,
  AVAILABLE
}

public Status overallStatus(EnumSet<Status> statusList) {
  return Collections.min(statusList);
}
```

Comment: +1.  This is fantastic.  Also, it's just called `min`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String listStatus(List<String> toCheck) {

    if (toCheck.contains("Not available")) {
        return "Not available";
    } else if (toCheck.contains("Partial")) {
        return "Partial";
    } else {
        return "Available";
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you ask ... in most cases, readability trumps performance.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good solution.  You could post a second answer - there's no rule that says everyone can only post one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
   public static String overallStatus(ArrayList<String> statusList)
    {
        if(statusList.contains("Not Available"))
          return "Not Available";
        else if(statusList.contains("Partial"))
               return "Not Available";
       return "Available";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `enum` class:

```
public enum Status {

    AVAILABLE("Available"),
    PARTIAL("Partial"),
    NOT_AVAILABLE("Not Available");
    private static final Map<String, Status> LOOKUP;

    static {
        LOOKUP = new HashMap<>();
        for (final Status s : values()) {
            LOOKUP.put(s.key, s);
        }
    }

    public static Status lookup(final String status) {
        final Status s = LOOKUP.get(status);
        if (status == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(status + " not a vaild status.");
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static Status getStatus(final Iterable<String> input) {
        final SortedSet<Status> transformed = new TreeSet<>();
        for (final String in : input) {
            transformed.add(lookup(in));
        }
        return transformed.last();
    }

    //Alternative method not using a SortedSet and getting the max on the fly
    public static Status getStatus(final Iterable<String> input) {
        Status max = Status.AVAILABLE;
        for (final String in : input) {
            final Status curr = lookup(in);
            if (curr.compareTo(max) > 0) {
                max = curr;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    private final String key;

    private Status(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

The `enum` encapsulates the status codes. There are `static` methods to turn your `String` status into an instance of the `enum`.

In order to get the current `Status` the `Iterable<String>` is transformed into a `SortedSet<Status>`. Enums are by default sorted into declaration order so all that needs to be done then is a call to `transformed.last()` to find the "highest" status.

I think this approach is better an `String` comparison as it encapsulates your `Status` and associated methods into a class.

I would recommend that you use the `Status` object rather than a `String` elsewhere in your code as this then adds type safety as well.

Comment: If you can handle having a `Collection` rather than an `Iterable` for the  input to `getStatus`, you can just use the constructor for `TreeSet` instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: @DavidWallace need to do the transformation in any case. I suppose I could use a custom comparator that did the transformation on the fly but I think that would defeat the object and also require many more lookups.

Comment: +1 just for using `Status` instead of `String` throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a better approach:

```
String currentStatus = statusList.get(0);
for( String s : statusList) {
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Partial"))
        currentStatus = s;
    else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("NotAvailable");
        return s;
}
return currentStatus;
```

This way you scan the list JUST ONE TIME.
If all the states are Available you final state is Available.
If at least one of the element is Partial and there are not NotAvailable your final state is Partial.
If there is just one NotAvailable state your final state is NotAvailable.